# How to Extend "CheckOut" Command in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to extend the "CheckOut" command of Tridion, and as of now I am trying to display my own message and am expecting the OOTB CheckOut action needs to be place when i click "CheckOut" option from the ribbon tool bar.

I have created the config file and .js file as given below, i have made changes in the System.config as well and created the virtual directory also. However my .js not fired and not displaying my custom message.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge" xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration" xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions" xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
<resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters/>
    <cfg:groups>
        <cfg:group name="CommandsExtensions.Commandset" merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.CommandGroupProcessor" merge="always">
            <cfg:fileset>
                <cfg:file type="script">/js/ExtendCheckOut.js</cfg:file>
                <cfg:file type="reference">CommandsExtensions.Interface</cfg:file>
            </cfg:fileset>
            <cfg:dependencies>
                <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
                <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
            </cfg:dependencies>
        </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
</resources>
<definitionfiles/>
<extensions>
    <ext:editorextensions>
        <ext:editorextension target="CME">
            <ext:editurls/>
            <ext:listdefinitions/>
            <ext:taskbars/>
            <ext:commands/>
            <ext:commandextensions>
                <ext:commands>
                    <ext:command name="CheckOut" extendingcommand="ExtendCheckOut" />
                </ext:commands>
                <ext:dependencies>
                    <cfg:dependency>CommandsExtensions.Commandset</cfg:dependency>
                </ext:dependencies>
            </ext:commandextensions>
            <ext:contextmenus/>
            <ext:lists/>
            <ext:tabpages/>
            <ext:toolbars/>
            <ext:ribbontoolbars/>
        </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
    <ext:dataextenders/>
</extensions>
<commands>
    <cfg:commandset id="CommandsExtensions.Interface">
        <cfg:command name="ExtendCheckOut" implementation="CommandsExtensions.ExtendCheckOut"/>
    </cfg:commandset>
</commands>
<contextmenus/>
<localization/>
<settings>
    <defaultpage>/Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage>
    <navigatorurl>/Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl>
    <editurls/>
    <listdefinitions/>
    <itemicons/>
    <theme>
        <path>css</path>
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration/>
</settings>
```

**.js file**

```
Type.registerNamespace("Extensions");

Extensions.ExtendCheckOut = function Extensions.ExtendCheckOut() {
   Type.enableInterface(this, "Extensions.ExtendCheckOut");
   this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.Command", ["ExtendCheckOut"]);
};

Extensions.ExtendCheckOut.prototype.isAvailable = function ExtendCheckOut$isAvailable(selection) {
   return true;
}

Extensions.ExtendCheckOut.prototype.isEnabled = function ExtendCheckOut$isEnabled(selection) {
   return true;
}

Extensions.ExtendCheckOut.prototype._execute = function ExtendCheckOut$_execute(selection) {
   $messages.registerWarning("This is Extended CheckOut");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410599/how-can-a-tridion-command-extension-find-out-the-command-it-extends gives a great example of how you can extend an existing.  Have you have a look through it?

Comment: Yes John, I looked into that, that doesnt have the complete config file. and based on that i have modified my config file also. but Js is nor fired. I think am some where doing wrong in config file.

Comment: As a first check: is your JavaScript being loaded into the browser? You should be able to find it in `http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx?mode=js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did, extending the Save button:

```xml
<cfg:groups>
  <cfg:group name="ValidateTitleField.CommandSet">
    <cfg:fileset>
      <cfg:file type="script">/Commands/ValidateTitleFieldCommand.js</cfg:file>
      <cfg:file type="reference">ValidateTitleField.Interface</cfg:file>
    </cfg:fileset>
    <cfg:dependencies>
      <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
      <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
    </cfg:dependencies>
  </cfg:group>
  <cfg:group name="ValidateTitleField.Views.ValidateTitleFieldPopup">
    <cfg:fileset>
      <cfg:file type="script">/Views/ValidateTitleFieldPopup.js</cfg:file>
      <cfg:file type="style">/Views/ValidateTitleFieldPopup.css</cfg:file>
    </cfg:fileset>
    <cfg:dependencies>
      <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
      <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
    </cfg:dependencies>
  </cfg:group>
</cfg:groups>
```

[...]

```xml
  <ext:editorextension target="CME">
    <ext:editurls />
    <ext:listdefinitions />
    <ext:taskbars />
    <ext:commands />
    <ext:commandextensions>
      <ext:commands>
        <ext:command name="Save" extendingcommand="ValidateTitleField"/>
      </ext:commands>
      <ext:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>ValidateTitleField.CommandSet</cfg:dependency>
      </ext:dependencies>
    </ext:commandextensions>
    <ext:contextmenus />
    <ext:lists />
    <ext:tabpages />
    <ext:toolbars />
    <ext:ribbontoolbars />
  </ext:editorextension>
```

[...]

```xml
<commands>
  <cfg:commandset id="ValidateTitleField.Interface">
    <cfg:command name="ValidateTitleField" implementation="Company.Extensions.ValidateTitleFieldCommand"/>
  </cfg:commandset>
</commands>
```

Then in my command implementation (JS) I used the following to invoke the "original" methods:

```js
Company.Extensions.ValidateTitleFieldCommand.prototype._isAvailable = function ValidateTitleFieldCommand$_isAvailable(selection) {
    console.debug("Is Available called");
    return $cme.getCommand("Save")._isAvailable(selection);
};
```

And finally, somewhere deep in the _execute method:

```js
if (!failed)
    return $cme.getCommand("Save")._execute(selection, pipeline);
else {
    this.loadPopup();
}
```

Hope this helps,

N

Comment: Thanks Nuno: I was wrong in the config file, now i am able to display my custom message for the "CheckOut" command. Actually i want to display the custom message after that the actual CheckOut needs to be happen. but now after displaying my custom message, the checkout is not happened.

Comment: I guess you have to make sure you still execute the CheckOut command as part of your _execute method. Also, you're returning true on _isAvailable and _isEnabled, I would recommend an approach similar to mine where I rely on the "extended" command to determine those values.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mismatch between the `implementation` your configuration file points to:

```xml
<commands>
    <cfg:commandset id="CommandsExtensions.Interface">
        <cfg:command name="ExtendCheckOut" 
                     implementation="CommandsExtensions.ExtendCheckOut"/>
    </cfg:commandset>
</commands>
```

And the actual JavaScript code:

```js
Extensions.ExtendCheckOut = function Extensions.ExtendCheckOut() {
```

You'll probably want to change the configuration file to:

```xml
        <cfg:command name="ExtendCheckOut" 
                     implementation="Extensions.ExtendCheckOut"/>
```

Comment: Yes Frank: I was wrong in the config file, now JS is loaded and i am able to display my custom message for the "CheckOut" command. Actually i want to display the custom message after that the actual CheckOut needs to be happen. but now after displaying my custom message, the checkout is not happened.

Comment: Command extensions are executed **before** the command they extend. If you want to influence the command itself, have a look at how Nuno invokes the original command in his example. Also have a look at `Tridion.Core.Command.prototype.invoke` in `Command.js` to see how it works and you'll see that setting `pipeline.stop = true;` may be needed to ensure the framework doesn't invoke the command after you have done so.